# Pass type as parameter to Oracle function

Tags: sql, oracle, generic-programming

I'm trying to write a function in Oracle that can accept a type as a parameter.

I've had a look around but can't find any examples, so I'm wondering whether it is possible.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
create function a_function
    ( text_in in varchar2, type_in in type ) -- can this be done?
    return type_in
is
    val_out type_in;
begin
    val_out := cast(text_in as type_in);
return val_out;
end;
```

The above should then be called like:

```
a_function('2021-01-20', date)
a_function('111', number)
```

Comment: You can definetely use types as parameters in pl/sql functions/procedures. I'm not sure you can use "cast" function in the body. Give more details - show the type definition.

Comment: @MaximBorunov I've used `cast` no problem with static types, but the use of `cast` isn't the pertinent part of my question. Have you got any example of passing a type to a function? If I can see how it should be passed, it should point me in the right direction. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you want to make your function accept *any* data type? Or a specific one?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov either way is fine. It doesn't need to work with any type, but I'm not concerned if the type can't be constrained.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, you should probably describe what exactly you're struggling with. Creating a function that accepts a type is as simple as `create function a_function (argName in typeName)` where `typeName` is the name of a declared type. Do you get any errors when compiling that function?

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I think you misunderstand. The function should be called like `a_function('2021-01-20', date)` or `a_function('111', number)`.

Comment: No, you can't do that. The closest thing you can do is to use `SYS.ANYDATA` which is "an instance of a given type, plus a description of the type". Why do you need that function in the first place? It seems quite a wierd requirement.

Comment: As Pavel says, the short answer is NO. Even if there was some way around the In parameter, the return type needs to be of a fixed type.

Answer (score 0):

Like many others programming languages you can overload functions. However, you have to put them into a PACKAGE. It does not work as stand-alone function. Would be this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE a_functions AS

FUNCTION a_function (val_in IN NUMBER) 
    RETURN NUMBER;

FUNCTION a_function (val_in IN DATE) 
    RETURN NUMBER;

FUNCTION a_function (val_in IN VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER;
END a_functions;



CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY a_functions AS

FUNCTION a_function (val_in IN NUMBER) 
    RETURN NUMBER IS 
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;
END;

FUNCTION a_function (val_in IN DATE) 
    RETURN NUMBER IS 
BEGIN
    RETURN 1;
END;

FUNCTION a_function (val_in IN VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER is 
begin
    return 3;
end;

END a_functions;
```

The call them properly e.g. with `a_functions.a_function(123)` or `a_functions.a_function(SYSDATE)` or `a_functions.a_function(DATE '2020-01-20')`

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm looking for an approach more akin to generics than overloading.

Answer (score 0):

The most generic approach I could imagine is to use anydata type.

So the function you need will be looking similar to this

```
create or replace function let_us_use_anydata(p_any_data in anydata, p_data_type in varchar2) return anydata
is
  l_varchar varchar2(1000);
  l_number number;
  l_date date;

  res anydata;
begin 
  if p_data_type = 'SYS.NUMBER' then
    l_number := anydata.AccessNumber(p_any_data);
    l_number := l_number + 1000; -- do any number stuff
    res := anydata.ConvertNumber(l_number); -- put it back to the output
  elsif p_data_type = 'SYS.VARCHAR2' then
    l_varchar := anydata.AccessVarchar2(p_any_data);
    l_varchar := l_varchar || ' Hi there!'; -- do anything you can do with a string
    res := anydata.ConvertVarchar2(l_varchar);
  elsif p_data_type = 'SYS.DATE' then
    l_date := anydata.AccessDate(p_any_data);
    l_date := l_date - 1; --  any date operations 
    res := anydata.ConvertDate(l_date);
  end if;

  return res;
end;
```

Using this function is something like

declare
      dummy anydata;

```
  procedure any_data_output(p_anydata anydata)
  is
  begin
    case anydata.GetTypeName(dummy)
    when 'SYS.VARCHAR2' then
      dbms_output.put_line('VARCHAR2: ' || anydata.AccessVarchar2(dummy));
    when 'SYS.NUMBER' then
      dbms_output.put_line('NUMBER: ' || anydata.AccessNumber(dummy));
    when 'SYS.DATE' then
      dbms_output.put_line('DATE: ' || to_char(anydata.AccessDate(dummy), 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
    end case;
  end;

begin
  dummy := let_us_use_anydata(anydata.ConvertNumber(12), 'SYS.NUMBER');
  any_data_output(dummy);
  dummy := let_us_use_anydata(anydata.ConvertVarchar2('Hello.'), 'SYS.VARCHAR2');
  any_data_output(dummy);
  dummy := let_us_use_anydata(anydata.ConvertDate(sysdate), 'SYS.DATE');   
    any_data_output(dummy);
end;
```

So the output is

```
NUMBER: 1012
VARCHAR2: Hello. Hi there!
DATE: 21.01.2020 08:37:50
```

Note there is a procedure using anydata in the anonymous block. This is here to display you can also detect the data type dynamically without specifying it in a separate parameter.

You may use any datatype aou wish, I just picked up those three as they are most popular ones.

Anyway, that was a very interesting case to crack. Thanks